# Replace 5 with 6 in python

Tags: python

I found a program of changing  digit 5 with 6 in python , but the issue is I've got it in python2 and if I change it in python3 and rerun it it gives weird output.

The source of python 2 code is

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-0-5-input-integer/

and my full python3 code is

```
def convert5to6rec(num):

    # Base case for recurssion termination
    if(num == 0):
        return 0

    # Extract the last digit and change it if needed
    digit = num % 10


    if(digit == 5):
        digit = 6

    # Convert remaining digits and append the last digit
    return convert5to6rec(num/10) * 10 + digit

# It handles 0 to 5 calls convert0to5rec() for other numbers
def convert5to6(num):

    if(num == 5):
        return 6
    else:
        return convert5to6rec(num)


# Driver Program
num = 520
print(convert5to6(num))
```

The output it gives is 
170642.43254304124

SO can anyone point out that silly mistake that I left

PS: I need the program to replace the digits 5 with 6.

the expected output should be 620

Comment: try str(num).replace("5","6")

Comment: Thanks guys, Both solutions worked like charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `num/10` to `num//10`.  In Python 3, integer division with the `/` operator produces a floating point result.  To get integer division, you need to use the `//` operator.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `//` operator works in both python 2 and 3, so win win all around

Comment: @smac89 Yes, it's backwards-compatible with Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it mathematically, you could convert the integer to a string, replace the 5's with 6's and cast it back to an integer. The easiest way to do this would be

```
int(str(num).replace('5', '6'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working in python 3 is because of the difference in the behavior of division in python 2 and 3. In python 2, `/` does a floor division, whereas in python 3, it is a true division.

So in python 2,

```
In [1]: 11 / 2
Out[1]: 5
```

In python 3,

```
In [2]: 11/2
Out[2]: 5.5
```

For doing floor division in python 3 you will need to use `//` instead of `/`. So, you just need to replace `/` with `//` in your code.